# Unexpected Error?

Tags: python, machine-learning

so recently I have been testing with sentdex's machine learning code and came across an error as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\---\Desktop\Images\Foundations Picture\imagerecognition 
(1).py", line 61, in whatNumIsThis
loadExamps = open('numArEx.txt','r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numArEx.txt'
```

As for my coding, it came to be the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
#check if it works
from collections import Counter


def createExamples():
     #Below, the file will create itself after running the script
     numberArrayExamples = open('numArEx.txt','a')
     #Different Diseases
     numbersWeHave = range(0,7)
     #Different pictures of the same disease
     versionsWeHave = range(1,4)
     #creates a sample file in the directory
        for eachNum in numbersWeHave:
        for eachVer in versionsWeHave:
            #print str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachVer)
             imgfilePath = ''+str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachVer)+'.png'
            ei = Image.open(imgFilePath)
            eiar = np.array(ei)
            eiar1 = str(eiar.tolist())

            lineToWrite = str(eachNum)+'::'+eiar1+'\n'
            numberArrayExamples.write(lineToWrite)

#changing array to make it black and white
def threshold(imageArray):
    balanceAr = []
    newAr = imageArray
    #For every color, it would take all of the lighter colors to be white 
and all of the darkers colors to be black.
    for eachRow in imageArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)
     balance = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, balanceAr/len(balanceAr))
     #Changing the color
    for eachRow in newAr: 
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3]) > 
balance:
                eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255
                eachPix[3] = 255
            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[0] = 255
    return newAr

#pattern recognition. It compares pictures   
def whatNumIsThis(filePath): 
    matchAr = []
    loadExamps = open('numArEx.txt','r').read()
    loadExamps = loadExamps.split('\n')
    i = Image.open(filePath)
    iar = np.array(i)
    iarl = iar.tolist()

    inQuestion = str(iarl)

    for eachExample in loadExamps:
        if len(eachExample) > 3:
            splitEx = eachExample.split('::')
            currentNum = splitEx[0]
            currentAr = splitEx[1]

            eachPixEx = currentAr.split('],')

            eachPixInQ = inQuestion.split('],')

            x = 0

            while x < len(eachPixEx):
                if eachPixEx[x] == eachPixInQ[x]:
                    matchedAr.append(int(currentNum))
                x += 1

    print matchedAr
    x = Counter(matchedAr)
    print x

    graphX = []
    graphY = []

    for eachThing in x:
        print eachThing
        graphX.append(eachThing)
        print x[eachThing]
        graphY.append(x[eachThing])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4),(0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4),(1,0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)


    ax1.imshow(iar)

    ax2.bar(graphX,graphY, align='center')
    #limits y-axis to 400
    plt.ylim(400)

    xloc = plt.MaxNLocator(12)

    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)


#import images in here
whatNumIsThis('Foundations Picture/0.1.png')
```

When I read the guide for this code, it said that the newArEx.txt file should be created by itself so I was confused as to why I got the error. Can someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: did you call `createExamples()` first ?  Can you fix the indentation and can you show how you are running the program? I don't see any function call to  them...

Comment: Oh, I used partial of my coding. I edited now so that the entire code can be seen.

Comment: you never called `createEamples()` first... Like I said earlier call it first then call your function

Comment: oh, my apologies. I read that too fast, thank you MooingRawr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking it to load the txt file, but you're not creating it yet. You need to run `createExamples()` first. Then you can run `whatNumIsThis()`. Also, your indentation is off still. In `createExamples()` you name your variable `imgfilePath` but you call `imgFilePath`.